# Unable to run spacy on jupyter notebook which is install at 'GCE'

Tags: google-app-engine, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I'm getting following error when I tried to import spacy to the notebook. 
I correctly install spacy using conda distribution and import the language pack on it. My python version is `python 3.xx` and spacy work in the command line without any error.

```
this is anaconda information 
3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

But, when I try to import it to notebook it always give following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-75659705d2d5> in <module>()
      6 import nltk
      7 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
**----> 8 import spacy**
      9 from spacy import en
     10 nlp = spacy.load('en')

**ImportError: No module named 'spacy'**
```

Comment: this is run on linux 16.04 version

Comment: are you sure your notebook kernel is the same one you're using on your terminal?

Comment: I  think both same. How can I check it ?

Comment: the one on terminal is written when you start python, the jupyter one is written on the upper-right corner (below the logout)